# HTML5 video Stopped working in Mozilla firefox 41.0.1

Tags: firefox, html5-video, video.js

Recently my mozilla Firefox has been updated to 41.0.1 and site has stopped playing HTML 5 video which are hosted on Rackspace server.

```
<video preload="" poster="http://a35080557e7a03b9f1f1-86aee789662273f4e4ffb1bc62c5c3ee.r62.cf3.rackcdn.com/1443704408.jpg" class="vjs-tech" id="lessVid-1_html5_api" onended="return mymoreinfo();">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://a35080557e7a03b9f1f1-86aee789662273f4e4ffb1bc62c5c3ee.r62.cf3.rackcdn.com/1443704361201302222231382124.mp4"></source>
                    <source type="video/webm" src="http://a35080557e7a03b9f1f1-86aee789662273f4e4ffb1bc62c5c3ee.r62.cf3.rackcdn.com/1443704361201302222231382124.mp4"></source>
                    <source type="video/ogg" src="http://a35080557e7a03b9f1f1-86aee789662273f4e4ffb1bc62c5c3ee.r62.cf3.rackcdn.com/1443704361201302222231382124.mp4"></source>
                 </video>
```

I am using Video JS player for playing a video.

It does not give any error still does not load video. Please suggest!!

Comment: What has this got to do with PHP? PHP tag removed.

Comment: Do you mean Firefox? The original Mozilla browser died long before it reached version 41.

Comment: Yes, Mozilla Firefox browser.

Comment: Deleted the earlier answer, because although the mime type in your Content-Type header is wrong, that doesn't seem to be the whole issue. Firefox for some reason thinks the file is 3GP, which it can't play. From the console: `HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/3gpp" is not supported. Load of media resource ... failed.`

Answer (score 1):

I remembered this question after seeing the same issue in another question. You have a couple of issues, but the main problem is the format of the file is 3GP rather than MP4 and Firefox doesn't play these, even if it apparently did in previous versions.

The details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34360720/740233) apply here.

You also have an incorrect mime type - your server is returning `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. If it were an MP4, that should be `video/mp4`. The second and third `source` elements aren't needed, if you don't have a file of a type, leave them out

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.
Like you, I'm charging the video from another server using http protocol and I think the problem could be that the requested server doesn't send the mime type to your page, so firefox crashes. In the console, in my case, it says: "The Content-Type HTTP od application/octet-stream is not compatible..."